# Google universal tracking for windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-8

Is it possible to add google universal tracking for windows 8 phone.  I have implemented google analytics for windows phone, does it support universal tracking.

Answer (score 0):

I consulted with various mobile developers like Android and IOS and did more research on net and found the below said answer.

Latest Google SDK comes along with the support of Universal Tracking for IOS, Android and Windows Phones.  We don't need to do anything.